# How to clear LaTeX cache?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I'm executing `.tex` file using `pdflatex` and `xelatex`. Surprising getting different results (as PDF) in both. It looks like `xelatex` is picking data from some cache and generating output with some old data.

Can you please help me to understand what can be reasons for difference in PDF output?

Difference found are :

1. Background Image in pdf generated using `pdflatex` is correct, `xelatex` is referrring old image.
2. I'm fetching data from external CSV file; somehow `xelatex` is picking data from old CSV file on other hand `pdflatex` is taking correct data.

Comment: Can you explain what differences you find? There is no cache, other than the auxiliary files for lists (contents, figures and so on) and cross references.

Answer (score 3):

I found out reason for differences. There was one ".pdf" file with the same name as ".png" of background image. while using xelatex , it was taking pdf file as background which was creating this issue. Sorry, it was my issue; which i found after almost one day of analysis; so thought of posting it.

Comment: Glad you found it.  It is a known issue (not a "bug", really), although the symptoms may be mysterious.

Comment: It's quite annoying that the precedence list for extensions in XeLaTeX is `.pdf`, `.png`, `.jpg` while in pdfLaTeX it is `.png`, `.pdf`, `.jpg` (talking only about the more common). I believe that `.pdf` should come first in both cases.